# How can I deploy my Eclipse builds to Google Glass after updating to XE16

Tags: android, deployment, updates, google-glass, android-4.4-kitkat

My Google Glass just automatically installed the latest update (XE16). After rebooting the device it turned out that all my previous deployments are removed from the device and I am not able to install my previous projects anymore.

My targetSdkVersion is set to '19' so therefore I should be able to support the latest firmware (kitkat).

What do I need to do to re-enable the deployment of builds via Eclipse?

I tried updating all of the Android tools via Software manager and confirmed that all libraries from API level 19 are installed. Odd thing is that the console gives the exact same information before the update (\MyProjectFolder\MyProject.apk installed on device, Done!)

Answer (score 4):

Found the issue, we now need to add another permission to the manifest to enable deployment.

In Manifest add

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>
```

[Link from Google](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware#unlisted_commands)